# Pandas: add new rows with evenly spaced timestamps given a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have the following dataframe:

```
    value                 timestamp
20.713936   2019-03-04 17:59:36 UTC
20.871742   2019-03-04 18:08:31 UTC
```

I would like to add new rows to the dataframe depending on the time difference of the timestamp column (if its more than 1 minute but less than 15 minutes). It should look, although not exactly, like this:

```
    value                 timestamp
20.713936   2019-03-04 17:59:36 UTC
      NaN   2019-03-04 18:00:36 UTC
      NaN   2019-03-04 18:01:36 UTC
      NaN   2019-03-04 18:02:36 UTC
      NaN   2019-03-04 18:03:36 UTC
      NaN   2019-03-04 18:04:36 UTC
      NaN   2019-03-04 18:05:36 UTC
      NaN   2019-03-04 18:06:36 UTC
      NaN   2019-03-04 18:07:36 UTC
20.871742   2019-03-04 18:08:31 UTC
```

I thought of making a function that would do something like this:

1. compute the time difference between two timestamps and check
   condition.
2. If condition is true, find the amount of minutes in
   difference and use that to learn how many rows I'm going to be
   inserting (if minute difference is 9, then I'll insert 8 new rows).
3. Fill the new timestamps rows with increments of consecutive +1
   minutes.

Since Pandas is so powerful, I was wondering if there was a way of achieving the same goal without having to write these functions and avoid usage of if/for cycles.

I'm thinking just adding 1's to each previous timestamp is easier than finding an equally spaced timestamp vector.

I thought as well of doing this with the help of an auxiliary frame and doing an 'ordered merge' by timestamp, but I'm lost with this one.

Does someone know how to do this?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pandas.to_datetime` and `pandas.DataFrame.asfreq`:

```
import pandas as pd

df
       value           timestamp
0  20.713936 2019-03-04 17:59:36
1  20.871742 2019-03-04 18:08:31

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
new_df = df.set_index('timestamp', drop=True)
new_df = new_df.asfreq('1min').reset_index().append(df.iloc[-1]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
            timestamp      value
0 2019-03-04 17:59:36  20.713936
1 2019-03-04 18:00:36        NaN
2 2019-03-04 18:01:36        NaN
3 2019-03-04 18:02:36        NaN
4 2019-03-04 18:03:36        NaN
5 2019-03-04 18:04:36        NaN
6 2019-03-04 18:05:36        NaN
7 2019-03-04 18:06:36        NaN
8 2019-03-04 18:07:36        NaN
9 2019-03-04 18:08:31  20.871742
```

Comment: Thanks for this Chris. How can I make it do it only if the time difference between them is within 1 minute and 15 minutes? I can get the difference in a new column, let's say df['t_test']=(df['timestamp'].diff()>'0 days 00:01:00')&(df['timestamp'].diff()<'0 days 00:15:00')   How can I apply that to only the values that meet that criteria for the gaps in between timestamps?

Answer (score 1):

you should take a look at [pandas.date_range()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html). I think it is what you are looking for.